# Cannot connect to SQL Server using Microsoft Excel Power Query

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerquery

I'm having trouble connecting to a SQL Server 2008 R2 data source using Excel 2013 Power Query.

I have created a new Power Query query, and created a new SQL Server datasource.  I have specified the server name and database, but have not specified any specific query.

I am using SQL Server authentication to login to the database, and the connection is encrypted.

When I attempt to set up the connection in Excel Power Query, I get an error message: DataSource.Error:

No further error details are supplied.

I have checked that the SQL Server allows remote connections, and I have tested the SQL Login by using the sqlcmd utility to connect to the database server and database and run a basic SELECT query.

If anyone can shed any light on what I'm doing wrong, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this in 2017:

If you are using Windows 7 and above, use the driver listed in the ODBC Data Sources. The only case where I had to install a client and driver, was when I wanted to connect to an oracle database.

To setup and connect to SQL server, I opened ODBC Data Sources, selected 'Add', chose the SQL server option (not native client versions) and added the server and database details where prompted. Then test the connection from ODBC data sources.

My SQL server connections usually require full TNS info all the way from server name, then database name despite the claim that it's optional.

Comment: Thank you for this. Searching everywhere as to what changed. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the odbc driver?
I have run into this problem previously when I tried to connect remotely.

Comment: The driver is installed, but I didn't have a User DSN configured, so I created one.  This appeared to work at first, getting further in connecting to the database, and telling me that the encryption certificate didn't match the server.  I disabled the encryption and it connected and loaded data fine.  I then deleted the User DSN to test whether or not that had contributed, and the data still loaded...so it seems to have been a coincidence.  I removed the data source and tried re-adding to check I could duplicate it, and it's back to not working again.

Comment: It was an authentication problem combined with SSL certificate problem.  Not resolved it exactly, but worked around by not using encryption and re-entering SQL login credentials.